# capture high res/frame rate in x11

Tags: c++, linux, x11

I'm doing `c++` project which is screen recorder for high resolutions/frame rates on linux.
A lot of libraries on linux written in `c`, so I also use them.

I've already written screen capturing using `nvfbc` (only nvidia), but I want to code fallback if nvfbc is not possible to use or if other vendor card is in use, so I decided to go with `xcb` as it's faster than `XLib`, but I discovered that even in 2560x1440 `xcb` can't capture even 60 fps, so it's too slow for my purposes. Since it's fallback implementation, it's probably will be slower than `nvfbc`, but `xcb` is unacceptably slow. I found that `xcb` + `shm` or `xcb` + `dri3` will be more performant and more suits my use case, but there's really few documentation and it's quite difficult to find the best way for screen capturing. This is how I capture screen using `xcb` only:

```
    void X11Capture::load() {

        conn = xcb_connect(nullptr, nullptr);

        if (xcb_connection_has_error(conn))
            errHandler("Failed to connect to X server", -1);

        const auto setup = xcb_get_setup(conn);

        screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(setup).data;

        if (!isResolutionSet) {

            scWidth = screen->width_in_pixels;
            scHeight = screen->height_in_pixels;
        }

        isInitialized = true;
    }

    void X11Capture::startCapture() {

        if (!isInitialized)
            errHandler("X11Capture::load() were not called or was executed "
                       "with errors",
                       -1);

        isScreenCaptured.store(true);

        xcb_get_image_reply_t *image = nullptr;

        while (isScreenCaptured.load()) {

            image = xcb_get_image_reply(
                conn,
                xcb_get_image_unchecked(conn, XCB_IMAGE_FORMAT_Z_PIXMAP,
                                        screen->root, 0, 0, scWidth, scHeight,
                                        ~0),
                nullptr);

            const auto frame = xcb_get_image_data(image);
            const auto &length = xcb_get_image_data_length(image);

            newFrameHandler(static_cast<void *>(frame), length);

            free(image);
        }
    }
```

For now, it's like test variant since I do a lot of changes and measure performance. What can be used instead of `xcb` to improve performance and provide ability to be used on all modern videocards like nvidia/amd/intel and where can I find more documentation for all of that?

Comment: Have a look at the [MIT-SHM](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/xextproto/shm.html) extension ([example](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/blob/master/plugins/linux-capture/))

Comment: C++ code should not be tagged with C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @rustyx , I've found how this can be done using xcb + shm. There's example with comments from me for those who also struggle with finding how it works:

```cpp
#include <xcb/shm.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>

#include <sys/shm.h>

int main() {

    // Connect to X server
    auto conn = xcb_connect(nullptr, nullptr);

    if (xcb_connection_has_error(conn)) { /* do something on error*/
    }

    // Is needed to access screen/visual data
    const auto setup = xcb_get_setup(conn);

    // Getting screen from xcb
    auto screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(setup).data;

    // Generating id for our future shared memory
    auto seg = xcb_generate_id(conn);

    // Allocating shared memory for 1920x1080 screen
    auto shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1920 * 1080 * 4, IPC_CREAT | 0777);

    if (shmid == -1) { /* do something on error*/
    }

    // Attaching our shared memory to xcb, so X server will know what shared
    // memory we are talking about
    xcb_shm_attach(conn, seg, shmid, false);

    // Retrieving pointer to the shared memory and setting it to our buffer
    std::uint8_t *buffer = static_cast<std::uint8_t *>(
        shmat(shmid, nullptr, 0));


    xcb_shm_get_image_cookie_t cookie;

    while (true) {

        // Creating cookie for our image request. 0,0,1920,1080 are x-y
        // coordinates for our screen and width-height for our screen
        cookie = xcb_shm_get_image_unchecked(conn, screen->root, 0, 0, 1920,
                                             1080, ~0,
                                             XCB_IMAGE_FORMAT_Z_PIXMAP, seg, 0);

        // freeing image reply. Needs to be done as xcb says that we need to
        // free it ourselves to avoid memory leaks
        free(xcb_shm_get_image_reply(conn, cookie, nullptr));

        // At this moment, we can do what we want with our image. Image is
        // written into 'buffer' and in our case has length 1920*1080*4. Image
        // is encoded in bgr0, so for every pixel there's 4 memory bytes, 3 for
        // data and 1 for align
    }

    // Detaching shared memory
    shmdt(buffer);
}
```